# How To Delete Some Special Character in Java?

Tags: java, json

I have this JSON

```
{
   "example": "/My Files/Report/001/002.txt/"
}
```

I want to delete the "/ and /" on example and replace it with " only

and I'm expecting this result

```
{
   "example": "My Files/Report/001/002.txt"
}
```

I tried this code but it won't work (I store the example value in schema variable)

```
String schema = schema.replaceAll("\"/", "\"").replaceAll("/\"","\"");
```

Comment: Please include the expected JSON output, and also note that you should really use a parser here rather than pure regex.

Comment: I ran your code and it worked exactly like you wanted...

Comment: The same i ran too, it works same as you expected.

Comment: I'd recommend you parse the JSON, then update all string values using `replaceAll("^/|/$", "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are defining a new variable `schema`, but it looks like there is already a variable called `schema`, because you refer to it.  Redeclaration of a variable will always result in a compile-time exception.  If you remove the type declaration, you change the statement from a declaration to an assignment, which is what you want.  You want to reassign the existing variable `schema` to a new value which does not have the slashes.  Your new line of code should look like this after you remove the type declaration:

```java
schema = schema.replaceAll("\"/", "\"").replaceAll("/\"","\"");
```

That said, I highly recommend using a JSON parser over hacking together some regex.